# yii2 class validator does not exist

Tags: php, yii2

Class extends validators.

```
namespace app\myclass;
use yii\validators\Validator;
class telefoneValidator extends Validator
{
    public function validateAttribute($model, $attribute) {
        parent::validateAttribute($model, $attribute);
        if (!preg_match("^((8|\+7)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{7,10}$", $model->$attribute))  {
            $this->addError($model, $attribute, 'error');

        }
    }           
}
```

Class app\models\user  rules validation/

```
namespace app\models;

    use Yii;
    use app\myclass\telefoneValidator;

        public function rules()
        {
            return [         
                ['telefone', 'telefoneValidator']
            ];
        }
```

When you start getting error Exception 'ReflectionException' with message:

```
Class telefoneValidator does not exist
```

Comment: The autoloader probably can't find it. What is the file path and name of your `telefoneValidator` class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This declaration is for inline validators that declared as the same class methods (for example when you add `public function validateTelefone($attribute, $params) { ... }` and `'validateTelephone'` as second parameter of validation rule).

For external validators that stored in separate classes you should provide full class name with namespace like so:

```
use app\myclass\telefoneValidator;

...

['telefone', telefoneValidator::className()],
```

or

```
['telefone', 'app\myclass\telefoneValidator'],
```

*Additional notes:* I recommend change validator name to `TelefoneValidator`, since it violates framework classes naming convention.

Comment: Tried to use ['telefone', telefoneValidator::className()] error Class 'app\myclass\telefoneValidator' not found.

Comment: Make sure it's placed correctly in folder structure.

Comment: Exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class yii\validators\telefoneValidator does not exist' 

in C:\web\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\di\Container.php:411                            Probably somewhere in the project need to specify the classpath?

Comment: No. Where exactly is the file in folder structure?